# Flickering when using mouse in and mouse out

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an effect where when mouse is moved over the image it should display a translucent black box on the image and display some details on top. These div's contain images and the problem is this mouseover and mouseout event are creating flickering of the black translucent div added on top.

Here is the code,

```
function addfocus(elem)
{
  // getting dimensions of current div.
   var currelem = document.getElementById(elem);
   var left = currelem.offsetLeft;
   var top = currelem.offsetTop;
   var w = currelem.offsetWidth;
   var h = currelem.offsetHeight;

   // create a new div to match up these dimensions. 
   var ddiv = document.createElement("div");
   ddiv.style.position = "absolute";
   ddiv.style.top = top + "px";
   ddiv.style.left = left + "px";
   ddiv.style.width = w + "px";
   ddiv.style.height = h + "px";

   ddiv.style.backgroundColor= "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";

   document.body.appendChild(ddiv);
}

function rmvfoucs(elem)
{
    document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById(elem));
}
```

When there is only text in the div, the flickering is not seen. Only when the image is included in the div, do I see the flickering.

Please help if you have any solution to this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that when you add your overlay it causes a mouseout event which removes the overlay. So when you move the mouse you constantly adds and removes the overlay.

But I'm not sure why you use Javascript for this. It can be accomplished in CSS, using :hover.

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="info">...</div>
    <img src="..." />
</div>
```

Show your overlay on hover

```
.info {
    display:none;
}
.item:hover .info {
    display:block;
}
```

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/jj8X6/

Comment: I am using javascript because I have many dynamically created elements in my project, on hover over them I want this effect. Sorry as I didnt mention it. I will try your technique though.

Comment: I understood how I can integrate it now.